# Проблема с формулой в PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, float

Хочу сделать простейшую функцию прыжка через параболу, но столкнулся с тем, что в pygame позиция может быть только целым числом, а результат функции - дробное, поэтому с каждым прыжком уровень бокса персонажа повышается.
Прыжок:

```
if player.jumping:
        if jump_height >= -15:
            player.rect.y -= decimal.Decimal((jump_height ** 2) / 2) if jump_height >= 0 else -decimal.Decimal((jump_height ** 2) / 2)
            jump_height -= 1
        else:
            player.jumping = False
            player.rect.y += 8
            jump_height = 15
```

Весь код:

```
import pygame
import os
import decimal

# VARIABLES
WIDTH = 1920
HEIGHT = 1080
FPS = 60
player_speed = 15
running = True
jumping = False
jump_height = 15
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# INITIALIZING
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
main_window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("TestGame")
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

# ASSETS
game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'img')
player_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'player.png'))
player_sneaking_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'sneaking.png'))


# CLASSES
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = player_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - 100)
        self.sneaking = False
        self.jumping = False

    def move(self, direction):
        if self.rect.left > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = 0
        elif self.rect.right < 0:
            self.rect.left = WIDTH
        elif direction == 2:
            self.rect.x += player_speed
        elif direction == 3:
            self.sneaking = True
            rect = (self.rect.center[0], self.rect.bottom - (0.75 * self.rect.height) / 2)
            self.image = player_sneaking_img
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = rect
        elif direction == 4:
            self.rect.x -= player_speed


# FUNCTIONS
def movements_handler():
    global player_speed
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if (key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]) and not player.jumping and not player.sneaking:
        player.jumping = True
    if key[pygame.K_d] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.move(2)
    if (key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_DOWN]):
        if not jumping:
            player_speed /= 2
        player.move(3)
    if key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.move(4)


player = Player()
sprites.add(player)

# PROGRAM
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    # EVENT HANDLER

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.sneaking = False
                player.image = player_img
                player.rect = player.image.get_rect()
                player_speed = 8

    movements_handler()
    # UPDATE
    if player.jumping:
        if jump_height >= -15:
            player.rect.y -= decimal.Decimal((jump_height ** 2) / 2) if jump_height >= 0 else -decimal.Decimal((jump_height ** 2) / 2)
            jump_height -= 1
        else:
            player.jumping = False
            player.rect.y += 8
            jump_height = 15

    # RENDER
    main_window.fill('white')
    sprites.draw(main_window)
    pygame.display.flip()

# QUIT
pygame.quit()
```

Получилось немного стабилизировать это с помощью модуля `decimal` + отнимая каждый раз от высоты 8 пикселей, но мне нужен какой нибудь более универсальный/надежный способ.